# Associativity of an if expression in Python

Tags: python, conditional-operator, associativity

In Python language, which is the associativity of an if expression: left or right? For example if we write this:

```
<exp1> if <exp2> else <exp3> if <exp4> else <exp5>
```

what is the corresponding form?

```
[<exp1> if <exp2> else <exp3>] if <exp4> else <exp5>
```

or:

```
<exp1> if <exp2> else [<exp3> if <exp4> else <exp5>]
```

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation on operator precedence?